# How can I run old games from the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, interface, blend-files

I have quite a bit of old games and projects designed for the Blender Game Engine. Now, with the removal of BGE, these games cannot be played or worked further upon. Are there any other platforms for which I can run these games, and make changes or improve upon them?

Comment: The game engine is not included in new versions of Blender (2.8x), you can still use 2.79b and earlier versions. Alternatively [UPBGE](https://github.com/UPBGE/upbge) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Old versions of Blender are still available.  As long as they still run in your host OS you can just use one of those